# Windows phone store Query

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

We have an app which is built in Windows phone 8 silver light framework. As windows 10 is coming and we are trying to upgrade this app to Windows phone 8.1.

Our only concern is can we keep both version of the app on store? i.e on store we should be able to upload two different build for WP8 and WP8.1.

Let me know if you guys have the answer

Comment: I think this is available if each application had different "Reserved Name"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have two different versions in the store. But my question is if you do have a `Windows Phone 8` version of an application why do you need the 8.1 version too, where WP8 application would support both the versions?

You could have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655121.aspx#sectionToggle0), in order to migrate your app into Universal apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We want to keep supporting Windows 8 devices. So let's say we have around 10,000 users still on Windows 8 and haven't updated to Windows 8.1 so we want to keep Windows 8 as separate version and Windows 8.1 as separate Just like Windows app store